# How important is the channel order in deep-learning computer vision tasks?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, data-augmentation, image

I stumbled across this question while working with OpenCV, which stores color images in BGR order in memory, while most other libraries I know of use RGB order.

How important is this difference? Would I be able to use BGR images for an RGB-trained network? Obviously, a fire truck is red in most regions, and not blue. But don't CNNs look for texture rather than simple colors?

Even assuming there is a difference - could it still make sense to apply channel permutations as a kind of data augmentation during training? This would spread the spectrum of textures from each original channel to both others, again, the assumption being that colors are not all that important.

I would be curious to know if research like this already been done - I would be surprised if it had not.

Answer (score 1):

**Task dependent but could be important.**

Lets find some arbitrary representation that separates luminance from chrominance (represented as a color 2D vector)?
That way, you are detecting bright objects independent of color, and colorful objects **less dependent** on brightness. Obviously under assumption that you are color agnostic.
Check this paper where they applied exactly this [permutations augmentation](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SkliR1SKDS)

Answer (score 1):

> Would I be able to use BGR images for an RGB-trained network?

I think the performance will be much worse than RGB input.

### Color Permutations as augmentation

Paper [Rethinking Data Augmentation: Self-Supervision and Self-Distillation](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Rethinking-Data-Augmentation%3A-Self-Supervision-and-Lee-Hwang/88d08a5bd00a301455e0f6a454642550775fb427):

if the augmentation results in large distributional **discrepancy** among pictures (e.g., **rotations**), *forcing their label invariance may be too difficult* to solve and often hurts the performance.
To tackle this challenge, we suggest an idea of learning the **joint distribution** of the original and self-supervised labels of augmented samples.

Augmentation: two transformations which use the entire input image
1.`rotation (0◦,90◦, 180◦, 270◦)`
This transformation is widely used for **self-supervision** due to its simplicity
2.`Color permutation`
constructs M = 3! = 6 different images via swapping RGB channels
This transformation can be **useful** when **color information is important** such as
finegrained classification datasets

[image: 6(3x2x1) different images via swapping RGB channels]